Stack alignment in cdecl
The x86 calling conventions page in wikipedia mentions the alignment of stack in cdecl calling convention:

Stack aligned on 16-byte boundary due to a bug.

What is that? a bug?

Maybe this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38496
